# How to add existing table column in existing projection segmented by hash clause in vertica db?

Tags: projection, vertica

I have created one table and have one projection of that table. I have to add existing table column in existing projection segmented by hash clause in vertica db.

"I have to add SBS_ALERT_ID column in existing projection segmented by hash clause without creating new projection."

```
CREATE TABLE public.ALERT
(
AS_OF_DATE date,
ALERT_ID int,
LOAN_NUMBER varchar(20),
SERVICER_LOAN_NUMBER varchar(20),
SBS_LOAN_NUMBER varchar(20),
SBS_ALERT_ID int,
ALERT_TYPE_ID varchar(25),
);

CREATE PROJECTION public.ALERTTT_SEG /*+createtype(D)*/ 
(
AS_OF_DATE ENCODING RLE,
ALERT_ID ENCODING DELTARANGE_COMP,
LOAN_NUMBER ENCODING ZSTD_FAST_COMP,
SERVICER_LOAN_NUMBER,
SBS_LOAN_NUMBER ENCODING RLE,
SBS_ALERT_ID ENCODING DELTARANGE_COMP,
ALERT_TYPE_ID,
)
AS
SELECT ALERT.AS_OF_DATE,
    ALERT.ALERT_ID,
    ALERT.LOAN_NUMBER,
    ALERT.SERVICER_LOAN_NUMBER,
    ALERT.SBS_LOAN_NUMBER,
    ALERT.SBS_ALERT_ID,
    ALERT.ALERT_TYPE_ID,
FROM public.ALERT
ORDER BY ALERT.LOAN_NUMBER,
ALERT.SBS_LOAN_NUMBER
SEGMENTED BY hash(ALERT.LOAN_NUMBER, ALERT.SBS_LOAN_NUMBER) ALL NODES;
```

Comment: Show us the output of `SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('','your_schema.your_table',FALSE);`. Then, show us what column you want to add. Maybe we understand your question then.

Comment: I have added columns.

Comment: What I actually need is a small example of what you really want. 1.a) The table as it is before; 1.) The projection you want the column added to. 2. The column and its type that you want to add.

Comment: You cannot `ALTER PROJECTION` to add a column to it. Instead, you have to get the old projection definition as a script (`SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('','<yourschema>.<yourtable>',FALSE);` will do that for you); then you add the new column to the column lists in that script, you change the projection name, and run it.

Comment: Run `ELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('','<yourschema>.<yourtable>',FALSE);` for me, and add the output of that to your question - not to my answer. I will reject your "edit suggestions" now and wait for you to update your question

Comment: Done, please check my question.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Now - your projection is currently `SEGMENTED BY HASH(loan_number,sbs_loan_number)`. Do you mean that you want to "just" add  `sbs_alert_id` to the HASH() function call?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I already modified the bottom of my answer accordingly: create a new projection segmented as you want it, refresh the table, and drop the old projection. Do you need the script?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?
Initial situation:

```
CREATE TABLE segby (
    fullname varchar(12),
    dob date
);
CREATE PROJECTION segby_super /*+basename(segby),createtype(A)*/ (
 fullname,
 dob 
)
AS
 SELECT segby.fullname,
        segby.dob
 FROM segby
 ORDER BY segby.fullname,
          segby.dob
SEGMENTED BY hash(segby.dob, segby.fullname) ALL NODES OFFSET 0;
```

Then, you add a column and initialise it with a `DEFAULT` ...

```
ALTER TABLE segby ADD id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT HASH(dob,fullname);
```

And subsequently, you make sure the table is segmented by that new column, by creating such a projection:

```
CREATE PROJECTION segby_id 
AS SELECT
  id  
, fullname
, dob 
FROM segby
ORDER BY id
SEGMENTED BY HASH(id) ALL NODES;
```

And finish by running a `REFRESH` on your table ...

```
SELECT REFRESH('segby');
-- out                                                                                                                                             REFRESH                                                                                                                                            
-- out -
-- out Refresh completed with the following outcomes:
-- out Projection Name: [Anchor Table] [Status] [Refresh Method] [Error Count] [Duration (sec)]
-- out ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- out "dbadmin"."segby_id": [segby] [refreshed] [scratch] [0] [0]
```

For your specific question: It looks as if you would like to be able to fire a command like:

```
ALTER PROJECTION public.ALERTTT_SEG 
SEGMENTED BY hash(ALERT.LOAN_NUMBER, ALERT.SBS_LOAN_NUMBER,ALERT.SBS_ALERT_ID) ALL NODES;
```

This simply does not work.

You will have to create a new projection, segmented the new way, refresh the table, and drop the original projection